# Why colons precede variables in Common Lisp

Tags: syntax, common-lisp

What does the syntax, colons preceding variable in Common Lisp, mean? I've seen programs with such, and I'll present some sample code here, out of a large set of functions.

```
(defun expand (successorf node)
    (mapcar (lambda (action-state-cost)
          (let ((action (car action-state-cost))
                (state (cadr action-state-cost))
                (cost (caddr action-state-cost)))
            (make-node :state state :parent node
                       :action action :path-cost (+ (node-path-cost node) cost)
                       :depth (1+ (node-depth node)))
            ))
      (funcall successorf (node-state node))
      ))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They're not variables, actually; those are keywords. They're a special kind of efficient token, similar to “atoms” in other languages. It's a convenient, built-in way to pass named (and, almost always, optional) parameters into a function call.

http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html describes the syntax of function calls.

Answer (score 40):

**Keyword Symbols**

`:foo` is a *[keyword](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_kwd.htm#keyword) symbol*.

- interned in and exported from the `KEYWORD` package
- constantly bound to itself

**Usage**

Keyword symbols are used when one needs the combination of the following properties:

- a symbol is the right data structure
- symbols with the same name should be unique (by interning them in a package) -> package `KEYWORD`
- different packages are not needed or wanted -> package `KEYWORD`
- writing the symbol should be easy by not needing to quote them -> `:foo` better than `':foo`
- the ability to act as a variable with different values is not needed -> `:foo` evaluates to `:foo` itself and only to `:foo`

In Common Lisp generally symbols can be in a package (kind of a namespace).

An unexported symbol `bar` in a package `foo` is written as `foo::bar`. The double colon is between the package name and the symbol name.

An exported symbol then is written as `foo:bar`. A single colon is used.

If the symbol is available in the current package then is written as `bar` without the package.

**The package `KEYWORD`**

There is a special package called `KEYWORD`. A symbol `bar` in that package is simply and always written as `:bar`.

**Examples**

These keyword symbols have also these interesting properties: the symbols are automatically exported from the package `KEYWORD` (so `keyword::bar`, `keyword:bar`, `::bar` and `:bar` are all the same symbol) and they evaluate to themselves:

```
CL-USER 5 > :bar
:BAR

CL-USER 6 > (describe :bar)

:BAR is a SYMBOL
NAME          "BAR"
VALUE         :BAR
FUNCTION      #<unbound function>
PLIST         NIL
PACKAGE       #<The KEYWORD package, 0/4 internal, 5830/8192 external>

CL-USER 7 > (eq 'keyword::bar ':bar)
T

CL-USER 8 > (eq :bar ':bar)  ; quoted or unquoted, each subform evaluates to :bar
T
```

**Usage**

Keyword symbols are used for example as names in named arguments:

```
(defun foo (&key bar) (+ bar 10))

(foo :bar 7)
```

Typically they are also used in arguments to instance and structure construction.

```
(defstruct node state parent action)
```

`DEFSTRUCT` is a Common Lisp macro and it generates several functions. One of them is a function `MAKE-NODE`, which can be used as:

```
(make-node :state 'open
           :parent some-parent
           :action an-action)
```

Note: sometimes the data might also be a keyword. For example in above form, the state might be `:open` and not `open`:

```
(make-node :state :open
           :parent some-parent
           :action an-action)
```

Comment: You write: "An **exported symbol**... is written as `foo:bar`. *A single colon is used*.." and also "the [keyword] symbols are **automatically exported**,"  but your example shows `(eq 'keyword::bar ':bar)`. Why do you use the double-colon if keywords are always exported? Can `::` be used with both exported and non-exported symbols?

Comment: @GlennSlayden Yes, every interned symbol, exported or not exported, can be written as package::name . Only exported symbols can be written as package:name . Only keyword symbols can be written as :name .

Comment: For completeness, what about `::bar`? Does it still refer to the `KEYWORD` package, or would that now be some other form of global? Sorry for being a LISP newbie.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: :bar , ::bar , keyword:bar , keyword::bar are all the same symbol.  (mapcar (lambda (sym) (eq sym :bar)) '(:bar ::bar keyword:bar keyword::bar))  -> (T T T T)